# color in pdcurses on win32

Tags: winapi, pdcurses

I am trying to get a simple console program to work in windows (it works in linux). I uses curses on linux, and when moving to windows I found that the least troublesome way port my program was to use pdcurses. I have used pdcurses before in windows, but with the win32a addon. However, I would like this program to run inside the windows console.

The problem is that it just seems to completely ignore all color commands. Is this a problem with pdcurses on windows or am I just being stupid? Even the demos that come with the package don't have color. I am using MSVC++ express 2010 on Win7 64x.

`hasColors()` returns `TRUE`. When Ii run this simple example from the documentation, everything is still in black and white:

```
#include <curses.h>
```

int main()

```
{
    initscr();

    if(has_colors() == FALSE)
    {   endwin();
        printf("Your terminal does not support color\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    start_color();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_GREEN);

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    printw("This should be printed in black with a red background!\n");

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    printw("And this in a green background!\n");
    refresh();


    endwin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not fix anything, but I have found at times programs don't update color on GCC Codeblocks, and I add a getch(); at the end of it and it seems to fix any issues I have with color or adding text to a screen.

Make sure the getch(); is before refresh though

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing:

attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1)) 
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2))

after each print?

Add them and see what happens.

I'm using pdcurses with code::blocks under x64 win7 and I have no problems with colors. There's the off chance that only MSVC++ has this issue but I doubt it.